# Use sfdx to upload attachments

Tags: salesforcedx

Does sfdx support uploading Attachments?

I remember exploring their Bulk import API and I got nothing. You loose.

Thinking alternative way would be via REST API which should be reasonably easy via JSForce and the like?

Edit: turns out I can just upload attachments as a type

```
{
        "records": [
          {
            "attributes": {
              "type": "Attachment",
              "referenceId": "Att1"
            },
            "ParentId": "4567724823921244"
            "Name": "Demo",
            "Body": "AA==",
            "ContentType": "text/plain"
          }
        ]
      }
```

Comment: Did you mean thru SFDX CLI?

Answer (score 2):

You could theoretically use force:data:tree:import. Here's an example command:

```
sfdx force:data:tree:import -u sfdcfox -f attachmentdemo.json
```

Which could be from a file that looks like:

```
{
  "records": [
    {
      "attributes": {
        "type": "Account",
        "referenceId": "Acc1"
      },
      "name": "Demo",
      "attachments": {
        "records": [
          {
            "attributes": {
              "type": "Attachment",
              "referenceId": "Att1"
            },
            "Name": "Demo",
            "Body": "AA==",
            "ContentType": "text/plain"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

You can also use plan files, such that the files would be in one file, and the parent records in another, with the plan file tying them together. The Body should be a base-64 encoded file content.

You can also build these files by using force:data:tree:export to export data from an existing source by query.

Refer to the online documentation for more information.

Comment: Nice! Couldn't find any documentation about sfdx to attachments. Do you have a link?

Comment: @dzh I actually just read SObject Tree documentation in the REST API Developer Guide, then force:data:tree:import, extrapolated with an educated guess, built a half-dozen sample files until I got it to import in to my org, then posted this answer. You might say that this answer most likely is the documentation on how to do this, as I couldn't find anything this specific on the Internet (I usually Google first before building my own).

Comment: Worth mentioning in case anyone is trying to export/import attachments: it is not possible to query for `Body` using `force:data:tree:export`. Adding that field to the query parameter string results in a malformed query error.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you need to upload a single file, I don't think you need bulk API or even tree:import command, but just a simple command

```
sfdx force:data:record:create -s Attachment -v "Body=0KHQu9Cw0LLQsCDQo9C60YDQsNGX0L3RliEg0KHQu9Cw0LLQsCDQndCw0YbRltGXISDQodC80LXRgNGC0Ywg0YDQvtGB0ZbQudGB0YzQutGW0Lkg0L/QtdC00LXRgNCw0YbRltGXIQ== ParentId=0012D00000fgbalQAA Name=x"
```